# Why the operator overloading == is not working?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I need to check if these 2 vectors are equal using overload `==` but its always working only `else` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
class Set {
public:
    vector<int> mult;
    friend bool operator ==(const Set&, const Set&);
};
bool operator ==(const Set& a, const Set& b) {
    return (a.mult == b.mult);
}


int main()
{
    Set* set_1 = new Set;
    Set* set_2 = new Set;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
       set_1->mult.push_back(i);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        set_2->mult.push_back(i);

    if (set_2 == set_1) {
        cout << "True ";
    }
    else {
        cout << "False";
    }
}
```

Comment: `set_1` is a `Set*`, not a `Set`.  Why are you using pointers  for `set_1` and `set_2`?  Voting to close as a typo.  Get rid of the pointers.

Comment: How to allocate dynamic memory then ?

Comment: why do you need dynamic allocation here?

Comment: Its a requirement for my task

Comment: Can you post your requirements?  More than likely they want `Set` to use dynamic allocations, not `main`

Comment: I think what @NathanOliver says is correct. You can fix your code by dereferencing the sets, i.e. `if (*set_2 == *set_1)` but I am not sure if that's indeed what you want as it is very untypical for c++ code.

Comment: and how do I do that ? how do I make `Set` to use dynamic allocations ?

Comment: @Wr0ng Basically you replace the vector inside `Set` with your own implementation.  It sounds like your assignment is to implement a `set` yourself, and not use the standard library.

Comment: @NathanOliver so can I basically make a vector in main that dynamic allocates memory with type `set` ?

Comment: No, you need to code `Set` so in it, it has a pointer to memory that you allocate and expand as the set grows.  This is just a guess though.  Without seeing your actual assignment, I can't say this is what you have to do.  It's just the most likely scenario since most programming classes for C++ are like that.

Comment: I am not sure what you are using Set for, but have you considered deriving it from std::vector<int>, rather than containing a vector member. eg class Set : public std::vector<int> {}; You would get the == operator for free then + a lot of other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `set_1` nor `set_2` is a set. They are pointers to sets. You are comparing pointers rather than sets, and therefore your comparison operator - that accepts set reference operands - will not be called.

When you compare a pointer with another, you are comparing whether they point to the same object. `set_1` and `set_2` point to distinct objects, and therefore do not compare equal.

So, your problem isn't that your operator overload doesn't work, but rather that you aren't using that operator overload in the first place. To solve that problem, you need to compare the pointed sets instead of the pointers. In order to get reference to the pointed set, you can to indirect through the pointer using the indirection operator.

Or even better, you could have used set variables in the first place. There appears to be no reason to use allocate the sets dynamically.

---

P.S. Avoid owning bare pointers. Your program leaks memory.

Comment: That comparison operator _can't_ accept pointers either. There's already a built-in `==` for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Use inheritance for Set instead of using a vector member in the class. If you are dynamically allocated the Sets, then clean up afterwards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Set : public std::vector<int>
{};

int main()
{
    Set * pa = new Set; //If dynamic allocation is mandatory
    pa->push_back(3);

    Set * pb = new Set;
    pb->push_back(3);

    if (*pa == *pb) //Uses the inherited == operator from std::vector<int>
    {
        std::cout << "a=b" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "a<>b" << std::endl;
    }

    delete pa; //Clean up!
    delete pb;
}
```

Comment: While this solves the coding problem, deriving from classes that weren't intended to be used as base classes (in this case, `std::vector<int>`) is usually a bad idea. The original design was appropriate; this redesign is not.

Comment: @PeteBecker I take your point entirely, as I suppose we don't know how the OP might use the class down the line (eg store Set somewhere via the base class pointer).